# What is he singing?

Tags: listening

I have stumbled upon [一天到晚游泳的鱼](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3N-XHqPwdM) by Zhāng Yǔshēng. There are bits in which he sings but there are no subs. I would like to know what he is singing. Below, I'll identify the spots and try to guess myself.

4:49-4:52

La la la ?

4:52-4:57

cong bu jue bu ting liu    从不觉不停留

5:05-5:08

na na cang hai duo (me) liao kuo    沧海多（么）辽阔

5:09-5:12

zai ye bu neng hui shou    再也不能回首

5:21-5:23

qing yuan ? ? you    情愿？？？

5:24-5:27

qie chong mei you jin tou    ？？没有尽头

5:36-5:38

? ? ? ? di qiu    ？？？？地球

5:40-5:43

cong lai bu xiang hui tou    从来不想回头

Can anyone help me figure out the rest?

PS Is there a more appropriate tag for this?

**Edit:**
*Please, please, please* look at that video before answering. If I give precise time lapses, I expect you to follow them and listen, not paste parts of the lyrics that "it looks like" are the missing part.

That said, the only answer present now helped me figure out 5:36-5:38:

bu wen tianchangdijiu    不问天长地久

However, the rest is still not figured out, even 5:24-5:27, which is definitely *not* what it seems to be, namely 爱情没有尽头. Perhaps 却情没有尽头. Or perhaps 倔强没有尽头.

Comment: Here is the [lyric](http://www.5nd.com/gecilrc/51024.htm)...

Comment: Which _doesn't_ have the parts I'm asking about…

Comment: I already saw lyrics somewhere that went further and had the "Yu'er yu'er yu'er shui zhong you" part, which that one doesn't.

Comment: It was probably on [mojim](http://mojim.com/twy100199x1x3.htm). Now the final part there doesn't match the video, but still it goes further than the other link. _and_ the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really difficult to catch what he is signing in background. And actually don't seems to follow the original order of the lyric

4:44 魚兒魚兒魚兒慢慢游 (I think he join in the later half in this line)

4:48 游啊樂悠悠 (not in original lyric)

4:52 從不覺不自由 (not in original lyric)

5:05 滄海多麼遼闊

5:09 再也不能回首

5:21 只要你心里有我 (original guess, guessing first 4 characters)

5:21 情海护佑我 (Sounds 90% correct)

5:24 這情没有尽头 / 這就没有尽头 / 情就没有尽头 (The last 2 sounds more accurate) (not in the original lyric)

5:35 不問天長地久

5:40 從來不想回頭

Maybe someone have good ears can double, triple check :)

Comment: Mostly random bits of the lyrics with "minor edits" (e.g. aiqing mei -> zhe qing mei you). One thing: you are missing the first two signalled spots, 4;49 and 4:52.

Comment: @MickG I added back 4:44 - 4:52 :D

Comment: 5:21 is terribly hard. I tried to use an equalizer on it, and I think it starts with "zhi yuan" and ends with -ou or -o, perhaps "zhi yuan ni tingliu:" 只愿你停留.

Comment: Looking at the lips, it looks like "zhi yuan bu tongguo".

Comment: Or perhaps "zhi yao bu tongguo". 只愿不通过／只要不通过

Comment: @MickG 5:21 is the worst to catch. I played that 5sec no idea how many times yesterday and I was still guessing. However, I re-tried a few more times just now and it should be "情海护佑我". I will update the answer.

Comment: 5:24 actually sounds 這(就)没有尽头

Comment: Update: I just found [this](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%A9%E5%88%B0%E6%99%9A%E6%B8%B8%E6%B3%B3%E7%9A%84%E9%B1%BC/10708145). Almost everything there seems to match what I hear, except that 5:24 line where the link has 进退不由我 and the 进退 seems rather off. Maybe 青海不由我？ Or 情海不由我？ Almost sounds like qingkuang… 情况？

Comment: @MickG 5:21 情海多辽阔 5:24 只求没有尽头 <--- I found this in baidu (https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/408707120.html) Then I check https://youtu.be/w3p167DKkNw , It seems accurate. Those lines are not in the published lyric. I am surprise you revisit this after so long :)

Comment: I made an English version of the song and was making the draft for the related post on [my blog](http://michelegorini.blogspot.com/2018/08/blog-index.html?m=1) when, googling the lyrics, I found that baidu baike link. I am more convinced by the 追求 there than by your link's 只求, but I'll relisten to see if 情海多辽阔 convinces me more than my 情况不有我.

Comment: I'm going for a mix. The first syllable is almost surely 情. The second one sound like hang, I'll assume it's 海. The rest is almost surely 不由我. So I'm persuaded that line reads 情海不由我.

Comment: Update: I just realized I was relistening to another video :). Oh, and the one in the question is now blocked, so we'll have to refer to [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3p167DKkNw).

Comment: [Here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/31324/6273) is my take after considering all resources.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the video on the question has since been blocked. For this answer, I will refer to [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3p167DKkNw), which is hopefully the same lyrics. I think timestamps will change though. While drafting the blog post for the English version of the song, I found [this link](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%A9%E5%88%B0%E6%99%9A%E6%B8%B8%E6%B3%B3%E7%9A%84%E9%B1%BC/10708145) which, together with the lyrics, has also the lines I asked about in this question. Here are the lines:

1. 4:53-4:56: 沧海乐悠悠; pretty convincing match for the audio;
2. 4:57-5:00: 从不觉不自由; pretty convincing match;
3. 5:08-5:12: 你看那沧海多辽阔; this line definitely has 多么 instead of just 多, you can both hear the me and see the lips closing to say it; otherwise, pretty convincing match;
4. 5:13-5:16: 再也不能回首; absolutely right, this line is clear in the audio;
5. 5:24-5:27: 进退不由我; 不由我 is almost certainly right, 进退 doesn't seem to be; @John Siu found [a baidu link](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/408707120.html) which gives the line as 情海多辽阔; the first part sounds like qinghang or qingkang, or maybe jinghang or jingkang, so I thought of 情况, but I'll assume the -ng I'm hearing is actually a -i, so we get 情海;
6. 5:28-5:31: 追求没有尽头; 没有尽头 is clear, 追求 convinces me because I hear zheiqiu or zheijiu, though maybe it's 这就 with 这 read zhei?
7. 5:40-5:42: 不问天长地久; absolutely;
8. 5:43-5:47: 从来不想回头; absolutely.

**Bonus**

Here is the final text:

情愿困在你怀中
困在你温柔
不想一个人寂寞
无边漂泊
就象鱼儿水里游
你的心河流向我
不眠不休的追求

＊一天到晚游泳的鱼啊
鱼不停游
一天到晚想你的人啊
爱不停休
从来不想回头
不问天长地久＊
因为我的爱
覆水难收

多少喜乐在心中
慢慢游
多少忧愁不肯走
流向心头
就像鱼儿水里游
永远不会问结果
他们知道爱情
没尽头

＃一天到晚游泳的鱼啊
鱼不停游
一天到晚想你的人啊
爱不停休
沧海多么辽阔
再也不能回首
只要你心里
永远留我

女伴：
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿水中游，
游啊游啊游，
啊游到乐悠悠，
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿慢慢游，
游啊游啊游，
啊游到乐悠悠

＃

＊
（跟女伴：）因为我的爱
因为我的爱
（一个人：）覆水难收

女伴：
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿水中游，
游啊游啊游，
啊游到乐悠悠，
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿慢慢游
游啊游啊游，
雨声：沧海乐悠悠
女伴：啊游到乐悠悠。
雨声：从不觉不自由

女伴：
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿水中游
游啊游啊游，
雨声：你看那沧海多么辽阔
女伴：啊游到乐悠悠
雨声：再也不能回首

女伴：
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿慢慢游
游啊游啊游，
雨声：情海不由我
女伴：啊游到乐悠悠。
雨声：追求没有尽头

女伴：
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿水中游
呣呣呣呣呣
雨声：不问天长地久
女伴：呣呣呣呣呣呣
雨声：从来不想回头

女伴：
鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿慢慢游……

And here is my English rendition:

I'd rather be trapped in your hugs
And your tenderness
Don't want to wander endlessly
All on my own
Like the fish in water swim
Your heart's feelings flow to me:
A never-ending pursuit

* Fish that swim all day till the evening
They never stop
I think of you all day till the evening
My love never rests
Never wanted to turn
Did not ask for eternity *
Damage's already done:
I'm in love with you

How much joy inside my heart
Slowly roams
How much pain doesn't wish to leave
And flows to my heart
Fishes that in water swim
Never ask for a result
'Cause they know that love
Will never end

＃ Fish that swim all day till the evening
They never stop
I think of you all day till the evening
My love never rests
Oh the ocean's so vast
I can never come back
Just want to always stay inside your heart

Backup girls:
Fishes fishes fishes in the sea
Swim, oh, swim, oh, swim,
They swim so joyfully.
Fishes fishes fishes so slowly
Swim, oh, swim, oh, swim,
They swim so joyfully.

*
(with backup girls:) Damage's already done,
Damage's already done:
(Alone:) I'm in love with you!

Backup girls:
Fishes fishes fishes in the sea
Swim, oh, swim, oh, swim,
They swim so joyfully.
Fishes fishes fishes so slowly
Swim, oh, swim, oh, swim,
Yusheng: Happy in the sea,
Backup girls: They swim so joyfully.
Yusheng: Ne'er do they not feel free.

Backup girls:
Fishes fishes fishes in the sea
Swim, oh, swim, oh, swim,
Yusheng: Look at how vast the ocean is
Backup girls: They swim so joyfully.
Yusheng: You can never turn back.

Backup girls:
Fishes fishes fishes so slowly
Swim, oh, swim, oh, swim,
Yusheng: I can't help but keep
Backup girls: They swim so joyfully.
Yusheng: Pursuing with no end.

Backup girls:
Fishes fishes fishes in the sea
Mm mm mm mm mm
Yusheng: Di'n't ask for eternity
Backup girls: Mm mm mm mm mm mm
Yusheng: Never wanted to turn

Backup girls:
Fishes fishes fishes so slowly…

Answer (score -1):

沧海多么辽阔

再也不能回首

只要你心里永远留我

一天到晚游泳的鱼啊鱼不停游

一天到晚想你的人啊爱不停休

从来不想回头

不问天长地久

因为我的爱

因为我的爱覆水难收

鱼儿鱼儿鱼儿水中游...

From your pinyin it looks like that's the part you are missing

Comment: No it isn't. Parts of it are indeed in my pinyin, but that is not what I am missing. Besides, the subs have that. I gave precise timings refferred to the video, indicating _exactly_ the spots I'm talking about. The only value of this is in indicating that "? ? ? ? di qiu" is "bu wen tianchangdijiu". -1.